# Mule ESB : Error in Exporting and Importing the project in Mule studio

Tags: mule, mule-studio, mule-el

Please help me.I have developed a flow with reference files  and other message processors. I have placed "***wsdl***" in src/main/resources along with other xsd's. Also i used "***XSLT transformer***, ***Message property transformer*** and ***Datamapper***" .I have exported the project and deleted the workspace due to some reason.
         Again i'm have imported the project in new worksapce.I could see error in project,where **wsdl file** was missing. Script in the XSLT transformer is missing also Added properties in the Message Property transformer is also not there. In **DataMapper complete configuration is missing**.
Exported project-> Export->Mule->Mule Studio Project to Mule deployable Archieve-> Zipfile(local path location)
Imported project ->Existing project in to workspace->Select archieve file -> local zip file path location

Kindly suggest me the step in importing and exporting is a problem or anything else.
I have to write the script and add many properties from the starting.Please help me. My xml configuration after importing (Ex:given one flow)

```
     <sub-flow name="Common_ErrorHandling_SubFlow" doc:name="Common_ErrorHandling_SubFlow">
    <tracking:custom-event event-name="CommonErrorHandling_Log_Exception_Events" doc:name="Log_Exception_Events">
        <tracking:meta-data key="ExceptionCause" value="#[exception.causeException]"/>
        <tracking:meta-data key="ExceptionSummary" value="#[exception.summaryMessage]"/>
    </tracking:custom-event>
    <message-properties-transformer doc:name="Catch_Exception">
        <add-message-property key="" value=""/>
        <add-message-property key="" value=""/>
        <add-message-property key="" value=""/>
        <add-message-property key="" value=""/>
        <add-message-property key="" value=""/>
        <add-message-property key="" value=""/>
        <add-message-property key="" value=""/>
        <add-message-property key="" value=""/>
        <add-message-property key="" value=""/>
        <add-message-property key="" value=""/>
        <add-message-property key="" value=""/>
        <add-message-property key="" value=""/>
        <add-message-property key="" value=""/>
        <add-message-property key="" value=""/>
        <add-message-property key="" value=""/>
        <add-message-property key="" value=""/>
    </message-properties-transformer>
    <mulexml:object-to-xml-transformer doc:name="Object to XML"/>
    <mulexml:xslt-transformer maxIdleTransformers="2" maxActiveTransformers="5" doc:name="Generate_ErrorXmlStructure">
        <mulexml:xslt-text></mulexml:xslt-text>
    </mulexml:xslt-transformer>
    <wmq:outbound-endpoint queue="ERRORQ" connector-ref="WMQ_Connector" doc:name="ERRORQ"/>
</sub-flow>
```

I'm using version 3.4. Kindly suggest me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check out this [link](http://www.mulesoft.org/documentation/display/current/Importing+and+Exporting+in+Studio) atMuleSoft.

You can create a deployable archive `(.zip)` and export that as suggested in this link.

Answer (score 3):

If you import like the below process it will works.

File->Import->Mule->Anypoint Studio Generated Deployable Archive (.zip)->Select the .zip file to extract

Answer (score 2):

The export provided steps provided by you look good. And as the .zip file is aldo created for the export it is correct.

I guess the problem here is with the way it is imported.

Use the following import direction in Mule Studio to import the already exported project (in .zip file).

```
Import  ->  Mule  -> Mule Studio generated Deployable Archive (.zip) -> Select ZIP file from the local path
```

This should work.

Hope this helps.

[image: Mule Studio Import Directions]